# How MongoDB manage data after inserting?

Tags: mongodb

After data is inserted into the db, I know that MongoDB stores the data in files, however, I'm confused about memory.

Supposing  when I will insert 50 million records into the db - will this data be loaded in memory? If not, how does MongoDB behave to keep its performance?

Comment: I think some rephrasing might be needed. I have no idea what's being asked here.

Comment: Yes, it help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case documents are loaded into memory on request by blocks, that mean our collection is split-ed into chunks, and most frequent used chunks resides in memory. 
To gain performance mongo uses indexes and there is a special query called `coved query` which means that all data needed is stored in index, which is smaller than collection.